# Make header file dependent on external project

Tags: cmake

I have an external project that unzips a bunch of header files to `${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_PATH}/extproj`.

The problem is that I have no way of telling my various executable to build `extproj` beforehand unless I do `add_dependencies(myapp extproj)`.

I have a lot of executables though, so that's a lot of `add_dependencies`!

Is there a way to just do something like:

`add_dependencies(header_file.h extproj)` such that any app that `#include <header_file.h>` automatically knows to build `extproj`?

Comment: have you looked at [`ExternalProject_Add()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html)? You'll still have to add dependencies, but it maybe less. Also think about reorganizing your code so that you can chain dependencies better.

Comment: I *am* using `ExternalProject_Add`. How do I make my apps dependent on the external project for certain header files?

Comment: You don't. Reorganize your code so that your apps depend on a common library, and have that library depend on your external project. Additionally, you could reorganize your code _layout_ so each app is in a subdirectory. In your main `CMakeLists.txt` you would then have an `execute_process()` to always make sure your external project is built, then list your calls to `add_subdirectory()` to build your apps.

Comment: Actually, you could try `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ...)` to build a header or source file and add the dependency there. I'm sure it would work though as CMake doesn't treat sources as dependencies in the same as `make` does.

Comment: @nega thanks for the suggesstions. I'm thinking I may even just commit the header files to my repository so I don't have to rely on an external project to untar them. That would also resolve the issue.